# Is ''blurt out'' synonymous to ''jump the gun''?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Because they both mean to say or do something quickly isn't it synonymous?

Comment: No, they don't mean the same thing, though there could be some overlap in some situations. Neither expression really means to say or do something *quickly*, though they are about inappropriate timing  Also "blurt out" only really applies to speech, but "jump the gun" doesn't imply speaking (though it can apply to speech).

Comment: 'Blurt out' is a (multi-word) quotative verb. 'Jump the gun' is usually a complete predicate, though doubtless more avant-garde writers will have used it too as a MW quotative verb. "He's your father," John blurted out. / John jumped the gun; he told Anne before Jill had had time to prepare the ground. // But you should include linked and attributed dictionary definitions and sample sentences.

Comment: @nnnnnn what does blurt out really mean?

Comment: @DanielRigg It means to say something without stopping to think, usually something tactless or that should have been a secret.

Comment: @KateBunting does it also mean to say something unintentional?

Comment: @DanielRigg Couldn't 'without stopping to think' include 'unintentionally'?

Comment: @KateBunting does it mean to say something unintentional?

Comment: See my comments above.

Answer (score 1):

[blurt out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/blurt%20(out)):

> to utter with a sudden burst of strong feeling

[jump the gun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump-the-gun)

> to do something too soon, especially without thinking carefully about it:

Hence the two big differences:

1. one can only SAY things while blurting out, while jumping the gun can be any action
2. jumping the gun must be too soon, while blurting out can be at any time.

For instance, if someone was keeping a secret from another person for a bad reason, he could suddenly realize that this will cause a lot of problems and blurt the secret out, without jumping the gun -- indeed, while being vastly tardy in telling it.

Comment: Hello, Mary. On ELU, OP is required to give such basic research and say why they still have a problem.

Answer (score -1):

They flow along the same lines in a vague manner. But one main difference between the two is that the former is inadvertent, in most cases, usually provoked by fear, anxiety, etc. The latter, if you were to look up its synonyms and usages, you would know that it is mostly used in situations that are hasty. You could say *prematurely* revealing something.

Comment: If you were to look up its synonyms and usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Missing references?

Comment: please explain the meanings and differences of them

Comment: @DanielRigg I said there's just one difference, which I've stated. And the OP already has given the meaning, so I deem it unnecessary to reiterate it.

Comment: OP is supposed to do basic research. To look up synonyms and example sentences. Giving an 'answer' encourages further under-researched questions. _And giving an answer which itself lacks references_ ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Touché

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that the OP already gave the meaning, but their definition was incorrect.

Comment: @nnnnnn OP hasn't even defined it properly.

Comment: 'Jump the gun' means 'act before the _proper_ (as decided consensually / by subsequent events / ...)  time'. It needn't even involve speech.